# CordovaError when add native cordova plugin to cordova project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

first i init a cordova project like below:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello hello
cordova platform add android@7.1.0
```

then i execute cordova plugin add to install a native cordova plugin, then it happens like below:

```
JackRodeMacBook-Pro:hello jack$ cordova plugin add ~/Documents/work-flux/cordova-plugin/com-flux-location
(node:21287) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin /Users/jack/Documents/work-flux/cordova-plugin/com-flux-location via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "../../work-flux/cordova-plugin/com-flux-location" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jack/.npm/_logs/2018-07-10T10_17_06_259Z-debug.log
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:173:37
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:864:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:21287) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21287) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

i checked the native plugin directory, it has contained the package.json file.and i checked the network connection, it is also fine.

i cann't resolve it. anyone could help me?

Comment: Your plugin needs a `package.json` file. It seems to be missing.

Comment: @D.Simon but i'm sure i have package.json file in my plugin

Comment: The error message is clear. `npm ERR! Could not install from "../../work-flux/cordova-plugin/com-flux-location" as it does not contain a package.json file.`

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?

Comment: @D.Simon;@BShaps But although i wrote the wrong path, the error prompt is not show me a better tip like the wrong p@BShaps I resolved it. it just because of that i wrote wrong native cordova plugin path. The native cordova plugin path should be ~/Documents/work-flux/cordova_plugin/com-flux-location, but i wrote it to be ~/Documents/work-flux/cordova-plugin/com-flux-location. so it cann't find out my package.json file.

Comment: @D.Simon;@BShaps  But although i wrote the wrong path, the error prompt is not show me a better tip like the wrong path is not contained the plugin.xml